# java.lang.noclassdeffounderror when trying to embed an applet in html

Tags: java, html, wordpress, applet, noclassdeffounderror

I'm trying to put this applet I made in a HTML page so I can eventually put it on a WordPress page, and I am able to get it to show up but I'm getting the error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError com/google/gdata/util/ServiceException
```

Here is the HTML:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
    <title>CheckoutApplet</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      <object type="application/x-java-applet" name="checkoutapp" width=100% height=100%>
         <param name="code" value=CheckoutAppletWrapper.class />
         <param name="archive" value="checkoutapplet.jar" />
      </object>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to include `gdata` library in your `.jar` file. How did you create `checkoutapplet.jar`?

Comment: Always copy/paste error & exception output.  For e.g. here is no such such error or exception as `noclassdeffounderror`. It is `NoClassDefFoundError`.